# How to send MySQL connection information to data access layer from .NET user interface

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, user-interface, data-access-layer

I have a .NET windows application and a asmx web service and then a data access layer written in C# to communicate with a MySQL database.

My client have different projects. For each project we keep separate MySQL database. We have a another database say configdb, which have all the database information available and the connection information of all the databases.

When my .Net application runs we get all available database information from the configdb and display in a drop down menu for user to select the database which he wants to connect.

My problem is when the user select a specific database I want to send the connection information which I got from the user selection to the data access layer via web service and keep it until the user exist from the application. I do not want to send db connection information to data access layer in every call. Just need to do it once. Is it possible to do this? Or is there any way I can do this?

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: So you are starting from a Windows app, making a selection from a dropdown, and then open an additional form or the same one?  Surely you can open another form while passing the selected value from dropdown and using that for the connection string.

Comment: Not a good security practice to pass around connection information.

Answer (score 0):

On possible solution is to keep the connection information in a session variable.